# render string template containing Razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

in Asp.net core 5 , I have a string containing HTML and some code Like this :

```
var template = @"
                    @model int
                    @addTagHelper *, MyProject 
                    <div class=""AAA""><PartialTest some-id=""@Model"" /></div>
                    @{await Component.InvokeAsync(""Products"");}
```

and i need to render this to html string ,
i used RazorLight but it's not supporting TagHelpers and ViewComponents.

```
var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
                        .UseEmbeddedResourcesProject(typeof(MyController))
                        .SetOperatingAssembly(typeof(MyController).Assembly)
                        .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
                        .Build();


        string resultTemplate = await engine.CompileRenderStringAsync("templateKey", data,  10);
```

any idea for how I can do this?

Comment: As you said, the RazorLight not support it, can you explain more detail about what you want to achieve? If possible, you could create a simple sample to produce the problem or what you want to achieve. Then, we can according to your requirement to give an alternative workaround.

Comment: i want parse template outside cshtml with Component.InvokeAsync support